# What should I do to make the x-axis of a graph bold with Highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Note that the x-axis here means the horizontal line which corresponds the 0 value, i.e. the desired result is:

[image]

However, I can only achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0p14tu52/5/).

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
xAxis: {
    lineColor: 'black',
    lineWidth: 2
},
```

How to decide which horizontal line to be bolded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a line on the Y-axis at position 0. This causes for a horizontal line to be drawn at value '0'. This is done by the highcharts option `plotLines`

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {


    yAxis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 4,
        plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                color: 'black',
                width: 2,
                zIndex: 3
           }],
        },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the line generated by "plotlines" is not as dark: http://jsfiddle.net/0p14tu52/9/  Would it be possible to make it darker?

Comment: I took a quick look and noticed that the option `zIndex` fixes the problem (as right now the line is plotted behind the grey horizontal line). I've updated my answer with the change.